# Flatten DStream of List type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

### Problem

Hey, I have a `DStream` with type `List[A]`, what's the best way to transform this DStream into type `A`?

To help illustrate my goal, I want

```
List(A, A, A, ....), List(A, A, ...), List(A, A, A, ...), ...
```

to be

```
A, A, A, A, A, ...
```

Basically it's very similar to a flatten operation in concept. Thanks!

---

Update:
I think I figured it out, a simple `flatMap` should do it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: could you add the solution as an answer and accept it. That way you help other people looking for the same answer.

Comment: @maasg yea, the answer by z-star is correct. I just accepted it in case anyone has the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone want the answer. 
If x is some DStream of List[A] then applying a flat map on x where the transformation function simply returns the list, will flatten those lists into a DStream of A.

`val x: DStream[List[A]] = ...
val y: DStream[A] = x.flatmap(k => k)`